# C Use variable defined in file being included from

Tags: c++, c, include, scope

I am currently googling this, but I don't know how to word it. I suspect someone will point me to a duplicate question. But... if I have a file like so

**parent.h:**

```
...
include "child.h";
int foo;
...
```

and the following source file, which is called above via its header file:

**child.c:**

```
int display ()
{
    printf ( "%d\n", foo );
}
```

Now this is a simplified example, currently I am using C++ and I am creating an object, and that object calls a method of another object, like foo declared in the parent file. Naturally I get the following error:

```
error: ‘foo’ was not declared in this scope
```

Is there any way to get around this scope issue, or must I pass foo down as a parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [extern](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c/).

EDIT:

Adding some initial [linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-share-a-variable-between-source-files-in-c-with-extern-but-how).

Comment: For a function you just need the prototype `int display();`, which is often put into a header file.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, variables live in the source files...

> parent.c

```
int foo = 0;
```

...and are `extern`ed in the header files...

> parent.h

```
extern int foo;
```

In this way, whomever `#include`s `parent.h` will `extern` `foo`.

Comment: I think you made a mistake. Shouldn't `parent.c` be `parent.h` (without initialization) and `parent.h` should be `child.h`, correct?

Comment: @Puk14 No mistake. :-D But, there's many ways to accomplish the same goal.